# How te reinstall Unity?

Tags: 12.04, unity, nautilus

I have a problem. I  deleted some gnome packages , and now Ubuntu won't work as it should. 
Plus i  installed some programs for system tweak(new look of icons etc) and delete them and only left Ubuntu Tweak . I log in system and i cross with mouse over icons in slide-bar and name of icons stays but won't go away ... and desktop picture won't show up ... but 2d Ubuntu work ok but my desktop won't responding to left and right mouse clicks(marking,meny) ... ! And i can not see desktop icons but when i go in nautilus and go to home/desktop i see desktop  icons!?

I  clean unnecessary programs and they left of with Ubuntu Tweak and now unity work but and i can change desktop background picture but still can not use desktop shortcuts on desktop.

I always check out manually for updates but it is still the same.

*How to reinstall Unity to the latest version without reinstallation of complete Ubuntu .Txk.*
More you can find here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200383#post12904241

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo restart lightdm`

Comment: I try and it log me of and than i log in and it is all the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to show Desktop icons via tweak tool

[image]

Comment: It is a bit different Gui version but it is a good answer.